# Enabling Internet Proxy by FiddlerCore C#

Tags: xml, load, fiddlercore

i am using Fiddler Core API to track the Web Traffic. I can trace all URLs but when I try to load a file (suppose http://url.com/path/xmlfilename.xml) from listed URL, then Its blocking Internet by making checkbox tick in Internet Explorer Proxy Setting. And its stops Internet Working. So please suggest what to do now?

Its happening always with me. I load full Web Traffic then I try to load .xml file from list, then suddenly it stops working. Because Internetexplorer Proxy will be enabled at this time.

Answer (score 0):

FiddlerCore *is* a proxy; it works by pointing your browsers' proxy settings at itself. This is the default behavior, and this isn't what's causing the problem that you're encountering.

Please be more specific about what exactly it is that you're trying to do and what exactly is failing and how.

Comment: Hi EricLaw, I got this issue. Basically I was trying to load the XML from the link. But Fiddler provides the response on itself by session parameter. I think loading manually was the reason for this.

Also if there is any issue with connection like wrong URL or firewall setting, then fiddler stops the Internet by same thing. Charles software also did the same. so we need to close the software then open them again is only the solution.

Comment: Aah.. I apologies for my comment. Basically I was trying to show the response result, by loading file from URL, not from Fiddler API response itself. So I got stuck in that. I thought that it is the main reason, by which Internet is blocking? I resolved this issue by reading response from fiddler API. But now the main issue is, When I try to access any wrong URL then why Fiddler block the Internet, by enabling proxy?

Comment: If the requests that you don't manipulate aren't flowing cleanly through Fiddler to the Internet, that suggests that one of your event handlers is interrupting the traffic. Unless you share your code, readers can only guess at what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

I have added code like this

```
--------
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete;
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8764, Fiddler.FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default);
--------
void FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete(Fiddler.Session oSession)
{
    setDataInTrackList(oSession);
}
```

In setDataInTrackList function i am reading session URL as below

```
oSession.fullUrl
```

and loading file manually to see the result. But I was not aware of this before that oSession has GetResponseBodyAsString() function, by which we can read the response from API itself.